# How to properly set textarea height only without menu bar, toolbars and status bar in TinyMCE v6

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

Our application uses the TinyMCE editor and allows users to set the height of the textarea in the editor, that is, adjusting only the input field, not including the menu bar, toolbars and status bar. This works much the same as setting the rows attribute to a specific value. This solution worked great with TinyMCE version 4, but after updating to version 6, our solution had problems setting very small values, equivalent to rows="2" or about 40 pixels. Configuration options such as `height`, `min_height`, `max_height` do not work because they adjust the height of the entire editor, not just the textarea ([see documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/editor-size-options/#height)).

For now we are setting height=auto for `.tox-tinymce` and `.tox-edit-area__iframe`. We also set the `height = 'user value'` for `.tox-sidebar-wrap`. All these manipulations occur at the time of the `tinymcce.init` event. When the `tinymce.ResizeEditor` event occurs, all set values are reset.
This solution works but I hope there is a simpler solution.

Could you please help and point me if there is an easy way to control the height of just the inner textarea without using solutions like overriding the height property for certain TinyMCE classes in CSS.

Thanks in advance for your help.